# How can I create organizational chart in inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, diagram

I have lots of problem with inkscape connectors incluing these
1. when Icopy/pase a connector everything changed!
2. can not break a connector alone!

now I do not know how to creat some organizational chart like diagrams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkscape connector tool is very basic. You could try filing bugs at https://launchpad.net/inkscape.

In the short term if you're feeling hardcore you could experiment with something like GraphViz http://graphviz.org/About.php

Comment: hi thank you very much it would help me very much but do you have any Idea about the addon or something in inkscape?

Comment: There is no such addon that I know of